ISC-DHCP-Server responds on 127.0.0.1 (lo) interface instead of the correct interface preventing ip assignments
I am running ISC-DHCP-Server version isc-dhcpd-4.4.1 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. When a DHCP request is provided, instead of replying on the same interface, it replies back on loopback (127.0.0.1):
23:01:51.943114 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 44:3d:54:13:6b:6f, length 321 23:01:52.944092 IP **127.0.0.1.67** > 192.168.8.141.68: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300

It should be replying on 192.168.8.8.67. The machine requesting the IP address never receives the response because the reply is on loopback. I've limited the interface in the /etc/defaults/isc-dhcp-server
INTERFACESv4="eno1"
ipv6 is disabled on the server.
The same settings works fine on a different server (arch linux) using ISC-DHCP-Server version 4.4.3-P1. (I copied the dhcpd.conf from the arch server)
I am temped to compile a newer version of isc-dhcp-server, because perhaps this is an issue with 4.4.1, but I am hoping there is another solution.

"It should be replying on 192.168.8.8.67" - what does your routing table say?

Nothing. there is only a route for default gateway to the internet interface. Same routing as the other machine running arch linux:   "192.168.8.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno1"

If you only have one route and it's pointing to your default gw, there's something VERY wrong with your network config. Please add the output of ip route to your question.

Cause:
I had provided the FQDN of the server for Loopback (127.0.0.1) in /etc/host & dhcpd.conf file had option domain-name "servername.domainname.com" (FQDN). Thus it was pulling the IP address from the host file using 127.0.0.1 as the server address.
Solution:
I removed the FQDN for 127.0.0.1 in the /etc/host file & restarted the dhcpd service & it started using the correct IP address.
